# How to disable input in a children element of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need your help! This is an example of my table code:

```
<table id='tableName'>
 <tbody id='tbody1'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input.../>
    <input.../>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody id='tbody2'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input.../>
    <input.../>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I disable all inputs in tbody2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for jquery 1.6+:

```
 $("#tbody2 input").prop('disabled', true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9TSN9/)**

for jquery 1.5 and below :

```
 $("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with pure html and no javascript libraries, add the 'disabled' attribute to your inputs, like this:

```
<table id='tableName'>
 <tbody id='tbody1'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input.../>
    <input.../>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody id='tbody2'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input... disabled />
    <input... disabled />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

You could also set the to readonly, if you like:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript

```
var body2Inputs = document.getElementById('body2').getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

for(var i = 0 ; i < body2Inputs.length; i++)
    body2Inputs[i].disabled = true;
```

You Must Know things in JavaScript just in case you don't need to use Libraries like jQuery